# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: during migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration, database-migration

I was trying to create a migration in laravel using the code here. But unfortunately it pops out an error like given here. 
I saw some answers that i create the table manually.. but that would be so much against the whole idea of migrations.. no?

The migration file 2018_05_05_203731_create_cities_table is here:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCitiesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->text('Name');
            $table->json('info');
            $table->integer('country_id');
            $table->float('lat');
            $table->float('lon');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

The error that was churned out is here:

> C:\Users\think\Documents\NZ\blog>php artisan migrate
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: 
>   database "tripplan1" does not exist (SQL: select * from
>   information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name =
>   migrations)
>                                                                                         es not exist")  at
>   C:\Users\think\Documents\NZ\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databasee\Connection.php:458\Connection.php:664
>   660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query,
>   we'll format the error
>   e\Connection.php:458
>       661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a    662|         // lot more helpful to the
>   developer instead of just the database's errors.
>       663|         catch (Exception $e) {
>
> > 664|             throw new QueryException(
> >         665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> >         666|             );
> >         667|         }
>
> C:\Users\think\Documents\NZ\blog>php artisan migrate Migration table
>   created successfully.
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined
>   table: 7 ERROR:  relation "cities" does not exist (SQL: alter table
>   "cities" add column "id" serial primary key not null, add column
>   "created_at" timestamp(0) without time zone null, add column
>   "updated_at" timestamp(0) without time zone null, add column "Name"
>   text not null, add column "info" json not null, add column
>   "country_id" integer not null, add column "lat" double precision not
>   null, add column "lon" double precision not null)   at
>   C:\Users\think\Documents\NZ\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
>       660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
>       661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
>       662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
>       663|         catch (Exception $e) {
>
> > 664|             throw new QueryException(
> >         665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> >         666|             );
> >         667|         }                                                                        668|
>
> ```
>                                           Exception trace:
> ```
>
> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: 
>   relation "cities" does not exist")
>                                                                          C:\Users\think\Documents\NZ\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
>   2   PDOStatement::execute()
>         C:\Users\think\Documents\NZ\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Edit: The whole error was wrongly entered. The database name was corrected...

Comment: Aah sorry. that was the error once. I removed that error. But by mistake posted both the errrors here. Have corrected the error now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `Schema::table` to `Schema::create` in the `up()` method.

Comment: Aaah what a blunder.. Thanks a ton :D

Comment: Thanks so much. Experienced same issue, you saved my life.